# App Crashes: Memory issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

I was experimenting a little with Sprite Kit, and I noticed that when I let my app run for a while it crashes.

What I'm trying to do, is to draw a line that follows my player movement, I did this like so:

```
var ref: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
var shapeLine: SKShapeNode!

override func update (){

shapeLine.removeFromParent()

CGPathAddLineToPoint(ref, nil, player.position.x, player.position.y) 

shapeLine = SKShapeNode(path: ref)
shapeLine.lineWidth = 3
shapeLine.path = ref

addChild(shapeLine)
}
```

And this works pretty fine, I remove the node everytime, updating the path, and creating another node with the new path.

The point is that after some seconds (around 25) it crashes. 
The nodes are constant since I add and remove everytime one. The framerate starts to decrease right before crashing and goes from 30fps to 20fps.

What I find strange is the use of memory, it increases a lot, getting even to use around 800mb before crashing.

Is there something I'm forgetting, or is it just that the Path increases too much to be handled?

Comment: Why don't you try as an experiment to just change the path of the already existing `shapeLine` to see if part of the issue is from the continual creation of a new `SKShapeNode`. In other words, create `shapeLine` once and then for the other times, just update the path.

Comment: Already tried, gives the same result :/

Comment: How often is this run? Every frame? For example for the 25 seconds, how many times has `update` been called?

Comment: What do you mean? I already wrote the framerate, take as average 25fps, so 25fps * 25s gives how many times does udate get called

Comment: But I also noticed that it is 25s just with the properties that the player had, if I change some properties as the velocity it can also crash in 5s or so. I'm pretty convinced that it's a Bug like Alessandro said, who answered!

Comment: You are the one asking for help, correct? Then what is wrong for asking the actual count? I don't think it warrants a snarky reply of "I already wrote the framerate". Has it ever dawned on you in truly measuring? What if update is called more than you think? Or less? Those are all possible pieces of info that may (or may not) be helpful. It certainly could be what Alessandro has cited, however, until you have proof you are working on conjecture.

Comment: I really didn't mean to offend you! I'm kinda new to mobile developing, so it was a genuine question from me to ask "what do you mean?" So that I could better understand how this infos could help me. So maybe I formulate again, isn't the framerate alrrady telling me how many times update gets called? I tried different things and the framerate stays between 20 and 30 but at the end it crashes randomly if we doesn't consider how the object moves. I will edit my question adding some images, maybe it could help!

Comment: Your problem is that you just keep calling CGPathAddLineToPoint() to add a point over and over. That just keep allocating memory. Of course it is going to crash at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `SKShapeNode` is bugged, there are many bugs around this library component, most of these are reported [here](http://www.openradar.me/search?query=skshapenode).

You can convert a `SKShapeNode` to a texture (`textureFromNode`) than use it with `SKSpriteNode`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, what do you mean by using the 'textureFromNode', could you please give an example on how ti use this and let it work, since I couldn't manage to